# Use MySQL LAG() within inner join iteratively

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have two tables that I need to join iteratively within a loop to create values to populate one of the tables.  **I'm primarily looking for the cleanest way to do a one-period-shifted join, details below.**  Sample of the two input tables below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS holdings;

CREATE TABLE holdings
(date DATE NOT NULL
,ticker CHAR(4) NOT NULL
,wgt DECIMAL(5,2)
,PRIMARY KEY(date,ticker)
);

INSERT INTO holdings VALUES
('2019-03-29','MTUM',0.2),
('2019-03-29','QUAL',0.2),
('2019-03-29','SIZE',0.2),
('2019-03-29','USMV',0.2),
('2019-03-29','VLUE',0.2),
('2019-06-28','MTUM',0.2),
('2019-06-28','QUAL',0.2),
('2019-06-28','SIZE',0.2),
('2019-06-28','USMV',0.2),
('2019-06-28','VLUE',0.2);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS returns;

CREATE TABLE returns
(monthEnd  DATE NOT NULL
,ticker CHAR(4) NOT NULL
,ret DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(monthend,ticker)
);

INSERT INTO returns VALUES
('2019-03-29',  'USMV' ,   0.02715291),
('2019-03-29',  'SIZE' ,   0.00512113),
('2019-03-29',  'VLUE' ,  -0.00943159),
('2019-03-29',  'MTUM' ,   0.02118479),
('2019-03-29',  'QUAL' ,   0.02533432),
('2019-04-30',  'USMV' ,   0.02176873),
('2019-04-30',  'SIZE' ,   0.03818616),
('2019-04-30',  'VLUE' ,   0.03418481),
('2019-04-30',  'MTUM' ,   0.02255305),
('2019-04-30',  'QUAL' ,   0.03794464),
('2019-05-31',  'VLUE' ,  -0.09601646),
('2019-05-31',  'MTUM' ,  -0.02196844),
('2019-05-31',  'QUAL' ,  -0.06582526),
('2019-05-31',  'USMV' ,  -0.01614514),
('2019-05-31',  'SIZE' ,  -0.06918445),
('2019-06-28',  'QUAL' ,   0.07073081),
('2019-06-28',  'VLUE' ,   0.09571038),
('2019-06-28',  'MTUM' ,   0.06121113),
('2019-06-28',  'USMV' ,   0.04984654),
('2019-06-28',  'SIZE' ,   0.07531133),
('2019-07-31',  'QUAL' ,   0.013775  ),
('2019-07-31',  'MTUM' ,   0.01795953),
('2019-07-31',  'SIZE' ,   0.01208791),
('2019-07-31',  'VLUE' ,   0.01601182),
('2019-07-31',  'USMV' ,   0.01668555);
```

First step here is to join **holdings** to **returns**, shifting date alignment by one period, such that output from the first iteration is as follows:

```
date    portName    ticker  wgt monthEnd    ticker  ret
2019-03-29  test    MTUM    0.2 2019-04-30  MTUM    0.02255305
2019-03-29  test    QUAL    0.2 2019-04-30  QUAL    0.03794464
2019-03-29  test    SIZE    0.2 2019-04-30  SIZE    0.03818616
2019-03-29  test    USMV    0.2 2019-04-30  USMV    0.02176873
2019-03-29  test    VLUE    0.2 2019-04-30  VLUE    0.03418481
```

At this point, `wgt` and `ret` are combined to give a new `wgt` for each entry (calculation omitted for simplicity).  These new weights are inserted into the **holdings** table and these records look as follows:

```
date    portName    ticker  wgt
2019-04-30  test    MTUM    0.201442484998052
2019-04-30  test    QUAL    0.202261035805858
2019-04-30  test    SIZE    0.198273711216605
2019-04-30  test    USMV    0.202619777232855
2019-04-30  test    VLUE    0.19540299074663
```

Next step is to apply the same procedure as before, taking these weights, joining with one-period-shifted return, to produce output that looks like this:

```
date    portName    ticker  wgt monthEnd    ticker  ret
2019-04-30  test    MTUM    0.201442484998052   2019-05-31  MTUM    -0.02196844
2019-04-30  test    QUAL    0.202261035805858   2019-05-31  QUAL    -0.06582526
2019-04-30  test    SIZE    0.198273711216605   2019-05-31  SIZE    -0.06918445
2019-04-30  test    USMV    0.202619777232855   2019-05-31  USMV    -0.01614514
2019-04-30  test    VLUE    0.19540299074663    2019-05-31  VLUE    -0.09601646
```

We again combine `wgt` and `ret` to determine new `wgt` values and insert these into the **holdings** table.

This continues for all dates until we reach the end of our list of dates (given the above example, the last entry in the **holdings** table would have `date` 2019-07-31).

One caveat, this process is used to populate the **holdings** table *except* when a date entry already exists.  In other words, we'd do this process for 4/30, 5/31, and 7/31, but would leave the 6/28 records as-is in the **holdings** table.

Desired sample output (for a subset) would look like this:

```
date    portName    ticker  wgt
2019-03-29  test    MTUM    0.2
2019-03-29  test    QUAL    0.2
2019-03-29  test    SIZE    0.2
2019-03-29  test    USMV    0.2
2019-03-29  test    VLUE    0.2
2019-04-30  test    MTUM    0.201442484998052
2019-04-30  test    QUAL    0.202261035805858
2019-04-30  test    SIZE    0.198273711216605
2019-04-30  test    USMV    0.202619777232855
2019-04-30  test    VLUE    0.19540299074663
2019-05-31  test    MTUM    0.205430582
2019-05-31  test    QUAL    0.201024226
2019-05-31  test    SIZE    0.198113682
2019-05-31  test    USMV    0.204236958
2019-05-31  test    VLUE    0.205066864
2019-06-28  test    MTUM    0.2
2019-06-28  test    QUAL    0.2
2019-06-28  test    SIZE    0.2
2019-06-28  test    USMV    0.2
2019-06-28  test    VLUE    0.2
```

My basic approach is to use a loop over a unique list of dates, first checking to see if the 'currentDate' value is already in the **holdings** table, and then joining before doing calculation as described.  **Looking specifically for input on the cleanest way to do the one-period-shifted join referenced above.**  I'm coming from SQL Server, where I would typically create a dummy 'rowNum' column which I could use (ie, a.rowNum = b.rowNum+1) to do the shift.  Wondering if there's a way to use the LAG() (or other operator) within the join, of if there's another approach that would be cleaner still.

I don't think there's a cleaner (ie, non-loop-based) approach as each set of entries depend on the last.  Welcome other thoughts on approach.

Comment: A 'period' is simply the next date in the sequence?

Comment: @Strawberry That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following; I'm still using a pre-8.0 version of MySQL (I know), so no windowing functions here...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS holdings;

CREATE TABLE holdings
(date DATE NOT NULL
,ticker CHAR(4) NOT NULL
,wgt DECIMAL(5,2)
,PRIMARY KEY(date,ticker)
);

INSERT INTO holdings VALUES
('2019-03-29','MTUM',0.2),
('2019-03-29','QUAL',0.2),
('2019-03-29','SIZE',0.2),
('2019-03-29','USMV',0.2),
('2019-03-29','VLUE',0.2),
('2019-06-28','MTUM',0.2),
('2019-06-28','QUAL',0.2),
('2019-06-28','SIZE',0.2),
('2019-06-28','USMV',0.2),
('2019-06-28','VLUE',0.2);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS returns;

CREATE TABLE returns
(monthEnd  DATE NOT NULL
,ticker CHAR(4) NOT NULL
,ret DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(monthend,ticker)
);

INSERT INTO returns VALUES
('2019-03-29',  'USMV' ,   0.02715291),
('2019-03-29',  'SIZE' ,   0.00512113),
('2019-03-29',  'VLUE' ,  -0.00943159),
('2019-03-29',  'MTUM' ,   0.02118479),
('2019-03-29',  'QUAL' ,   0.02533432),
('2019-04-30',  'USMV' ,   0.02176873),
('2019-04-30',  'SIZE' ,   0.03818616),
('2019-04-30',  'VLUE' ,   0.03418481),
('2019-04-30',  'MTUM' ,   0.02255305),
('2019-04-30',  'QUAL' ,   0.03794464),
('2019-05-31',  'VLUE' ,  -0.09601646),
('2019-05-31',  'MTUM' ,  -0.02196844),
('2019-05-31',  'QUAL' ,  -0.06582526),
('2019-05-31',  'USMV' ,  -0.01614514),
('2019-05-31',  'SIZE' ,  -0.06918445),
('2019-06-28',  'QUAL' ,   0.07073081),
('2019-06-28',  'VLUE' ,   0.09571038),
('2019-06-28',  'MTUM' ,   0.06121113),
('2019-06-28',  'USMV' ,   0.04984654),
('2019-06-28',  'SIZE' ,   0.07531133),
('2019-07-31',  'QUAL' ,   0.013775  ),
('2019-07-31',  'MTUM' ,   0.01795953),
('2019-07-31',  'SIZE' ,   0.01208791),
('2019-07-31',  'VLUE' ,   0.01601182),
('2019-07-31',  'USMV' ,   0.01668555);

SELECT a.date
     , a.ticker a_ticker
     , a.wgt
     , b.monthend
     , b.ticker b_ticker
     , b.ret
  FROM 
     ( SELECT h.*
            , MIN(monthend) monthend 
         FROM holdings h 
         LEFT -- if appropriate
         JOIN returns r 
           ON r.monthend > h.date 
          AND r.ticker = h.ticker 
        GROUP 
           BY h.date
            , h.ticker
     ) a 
  LEFT -- if appropriate
  JOIN returns b 
    ON b.monthend = a.monthen
d AND b.ticker = a.ticker;
+------------+--------+------+------------+------------+--------+------------+
| date       | ticker | wgt  | monthend   | monthEnd   | ticker | ret        |
+------------+--------+------+------------+------------+--------+------------+
| 2019-03-29 | MTUM   | 0.20 | 2019-04-30 | 2019-04-30 | MTUM   | 0.02255305 |
| 2019-03-29 | QUAL   | 0.20 | 2019-04-30 | 2019-04-30 | QUAL   | 0.03794464 |
| 2019-03-29 | SIZE   | 0.20 | 2019-04-30 | 2019-04-30 | SIZE   | 0.03818616 |
| 2019-03-29 | USMV   | 0.20 | 2019-04-30 | 2019-04-30 | USMV   | 0.02176873 |
| 2019-03-29 | VLUE   | 0.20 | 2019-04-30 | 2019-04-30 | VLUE   | 0.03418481 |
| 2019-06-28 | MTUM   | 0.20 | 2019-07-31 | 2019-07-31 | MTUM   | 0.01795953 |
| 2019-06-28 | QUAL   | 0.20 | 2019-07-31 | 2019-07-31 | QUAL   | 0.01377500 |
| 2019-06-28 | SIZE   | 0.20 | 2019-07-31 | 2019-07-31 | SIZE   | 0.01208791 |
| 2019-06-28 | USMV   | 0.20 | 2019-07-31 | 2019-07-31 | USMV   | 0.01668555 |
| 2019-06-28 | VLUE   | 0.20 | 2019-07-31 | 2019-07-31 | VLUE   | 0.01601182 |
+------------+--------+------+------------+------------+--------+------------+
```

Rinse and repeat.